# when I was growing up

Tags: clauses, post-modifier

a. All my friends when I was growing up have good jobs now.

b. All my friends growing up have good jobs now.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: It's not a question of grammar, but of whether the sentence conveys what you mean. (b) could imply that the friends are currently growing up. Common sense would enable the reader to work out the real meaning, but (a) expresses it better.

Comment: I think neither a) nor b) are very good... I would try for a c)

Comment: Yup, I'd go for a c] All my childhood friends… would be a lot less clumsy

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, this really requires a c)

Both a) & b) are grammatical, but neither easily conveys the intent.

You'd almost have to construct an explanation into your wording to make it unambiguous.
Something like

> All the friends I had when I was growing up have good jobs now.

This might be more easily interpreted, but it's tortuous.

It would be considerably simpler to abandon the 'growing up' idea & simply swap to

> All my childhood friends have good jobs now.

Answer (score 1):

A c) would be good to demonstrate intent however as far as American English goes b) is actually perfectly clear verbally, tho written down it doesn't sound correct

Comment: I should actually be clear about something else on the topic of casual language: I wrote tho instead of though, which is correct in informal slang but never outside of it. Typing on my phone, I'm conditioned to write it like that here